# Delete keys from RLocalCachedMap by pattern without unmarshalling values

Tags: java, redisson

I have two services, A and B.

Service A is a service that exposes an API users can use to configure the system and service B processes records according to configuration from service A.

Service B uses a RLocalCachedMap to cache various aspects of configuration using `CompositeCodec(StringCodec.INSTANCE, new MarshallingCodec())` for simple String keys, and marshalled values.

Service B cache configuration

```java
LocalCachedMapOptions options = LocalCachedMapOptions.defaults()
                .evictionPolicy(LocalCachedMapOptions.EvictionPolicy.LRU)
                .cacheSize(250)
                .timeToLive(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .storeMode(LocalCachedMapOptions.StoreMode.LOCALCACHE_REDIS)
                .writeMode(MapOptions.WriteMode.WRITE_THROUGH)
                .syncStrategy(LocalCachedMapOptions.SyncStrategy.INVALIDATE)
                .reconnectionStrategy(LocalCachedMapOptions.ReconnectionStrategy.CLEAR);
cache = redissonClient.getLocalCachedMap("config", new CompositeCodec(StringCodec.INSTANCE, new MarshallingCodec()), options);
```

Now service A doesn't have any of the classes on its class path from Service B so is unable to unmarshall the values.

When the user makes a configuration change in Service A, I need to invalidate keys matching a pattern from the hash and am attempting to do it this way

```java
String keyPattern = String.join("-", customerContext.getCustomerId().toString(), "*");
        LocalCachedMapOptions options = LocalCachedMapOptions.defaults().storeMode(LocalCachedMapOptions.StoreMode.LOCALCACHE_REDIS)
                .writeMode(MapOptions.WriteMode.WRITE_THROUGH)
                .syncStrategy(LocalCachedMapOptions.SyncStrategy.INVALIDATE);
        RLocalCachedMap<String, Object> cache = redissonClient.getLocalCachedMap("config", new CompositeCodec(StringCodec.INSTANCE, new MarshallingCodec()),  options);
        cache.fastRemove(cache.keySet(keyPattern).toArray(String[]::new));
```

The issue I'm having is that even though I'm just using `keySet()` I am running into `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.redacted.Class` as Redisson attempts to unmarshall the value.

Is there any way I can invalidate keys from a RLocalCachedMap from a service unable to unmarshall their values and have these invalidations propagated to other instances?